# How to combine rates of Changes?

Tags: electric-circuits, measurements

The question is "**If the rate of Change of voltage and Resistance is 3% and 2%, what is the rate of change of power?**"
I tried using P=V^2/R and doing
1.03^2/1.02 = 1.04 so the rate of Change for Power should be
(1.04-1)/1 × 100% = 4%. Text book says It's 8%. What am i doing wrong?

Comment: What do you mean rate of change of voltage and resistance? Like $\frac{d V}{d t}$ or $\frac{d R}{d t}$?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The trick here is to identify that you have a variation in $P$ from two independent variables. Hence, the variation can be written by taking the total derivative, or in other words
$$dP=\Big(2\frac{dV}{V}-\frac{dR}{R}\Big)\times P$$
Substituting $dV/V$ for 3% and $dR/R$ for 2% you get the correct result. If the answer is seemingly missing some explanation, please ask freely in the comments.

Comment: Hmmm... I think I have silently assumed that it is "rate of increase" that we are talking about or "rate of decrease" for both quantities, because I substitute the rate of changes with percentages of the same sign... So, to answer your question without being 100% sure, it wouldn't change things

Comment: According to your formula, 2×3% - 2% =4% we still get 4%, so I guess 4% is the correct answer?

Comment: Well, maybe we are missing something... But if the two rate of changes occur independently, I think this is the way to go... So, unless I think of something better, this is the answer I would choose. What is the book you are studying from?? Have you had errors from this book before?

Comment: It's a local writers book, found in only our country, and yes this had errors before. What they did is the used propagation of error formula. So they added a modulas before the coefficients, so it became 2dV/V + dR/R hence resulting in 2×3+2=8%.

Comment: But the error propagation formula is what I have used too, in a sense. Because the formula you mention itself, involves taking partial derivatives from the quantities that depend on the physical quantity of interest (i.e. the power). Why is the dR/R term positive?? Is there something I do not remember from my undergrad studies??

Comment: I don't know, they placed the coefficients inside a Modulas (Absolute value) , so -1 before dR/R became +1 and didn’t explain why ಥ_ಥ

Comment: Hmmmm... I am sorry, I am not sure about the answer. To be honest, I did not think about error propagation in the first place, but now that you mention it, it kind of makes sense. However, I still can not make sense of the absolute value.... In error propagation I know that we sum squares of uncertainties and then take the square roor and they are not doing that either.